# do i need server-side video streaming?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

we are implementing a website, where people will be able to watch videos, hosted both on our servers and on Amazon S3.

We are going to use one of those great jquery based players that support HTML5 Video - as the first version is targeting iOS Safari - we still havent decided which one.

anyhow, my question is: do i need a server side video streaming solution?
or if i just specify a 2GB video as parameter to the HTML5 video tag, it will play while downloading?

also if i need a streaming solution what would you suggest? ffmpeg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a streaming server (as in Flash Media Server) for that type of video. The HTML5 browsers can start playing videos when only a portion of the video file is downloaded, and can even do range requests so that you can jump ahead in the video to a point that hasn't been downloaded yet.